# How can I move only 1 application to second display in Windows 10?

Tags: display, duplicate

While using Windows 7, I was able to "connect to a projector" (second monitor), and choosing Duplicate, I was able to move only my preferred application to the second monitor.  When I choose duplicate in Windows 10, it duplicates EVERYTHING.  Is there a way to move only one?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Duplicate ALWAYS shows everything on the second display as the first - also in Win7 (it's the definition of "duplicate").

You want to choose "Extend" (e.g., by pressing winkey-P) - and then you can drag the desired window(s) to the second display.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Extend desktop with "Win + P", then select your app (window) and press "Win + Shift + ->" to move it to your right desktop (or left arrow to move it to the left)